# toSVG method not working on extended class with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm working on a project with Fabric.js.

Now I need to create a custom class and to export it to SVG.

I'm using Fabric.js tutorial to begin:

http://www.sitepoint.com/fabric-js-advanced/

Here is the javascript code:

```
var LabeledRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: 'labeledRect',
  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = { });
    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.set('label', options.label || '');
  },
  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.get('label')
    });
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    ctx.font = '20px Helvetica';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
  }
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('container');

var labeledRect = new LabeledRect({
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  label: 'test',
  fill: '#faa'
});
canvas.add(labeledRect);
document.getElementById('export-btn').onclick = function() {
canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll(); 
window.open('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(canvas.toSVG()));

};
```

Here the HTML:

```
<canvas id="container" width="780" height="500"></canvas>
<a href="#" id="export-btn">Export SVG</a>
```

Here is my jsfiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/QPDy5/

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every "class" in Fabric (rectangle, circle, image, path, etc.) knows how to output its SVG markup. The method responsible for it is `toSVG`. You can see [`toSVG` of `fabric.Rect`](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/rect.class.js#L183-L197), for example, or [`fabric.Text` one](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/text.class.js#L813-L846).

Since you created subclass of `fabric.Rect` here and didn't specify `toSVG`, `toSVG` of the next object in prototype chain is used. The next "class" in the inheritance chain happens to be `fabric.Rect`, so you're seeing a result of `fabric.Rect.prototype.toSVG`.

The solution is simple: specify `toSVG` in your subclass. Theoretically, you would need to combine the code from `fabric.Rect#toSVG` and `fabric.Text#toSVG`, but to avoid repetition and keep things maintainable, we can utilize a bit of a hack:

```
toSVG: function() {
  var label = new fabric.Text(this.label, {
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: this.left - this.width / 2,
      top: this.top - this.height / 2,
      fontSize: 20,
      fill: '#333',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
  });
  return this.callSuper('toSVG') + label.toSVG();
}
```

The "fontSize", "fill", and "fontFamily" should ideally be moved to an instance-level property of course, to avoid repeating them there.

Here's a modified test — http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/QPDy5/1/

What @Sergiu Paraschiv suggested with a group is another just-as-viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is there's no SVG equivalent to `fillText` so FabricJS seems to ignore it.
[My workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/wR9F9/2/) is to use a `fabric.Group` and build an inner `Rect` and `Text`

```
var LabeledRect = function(options) {
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: options.width,
        height: options.height,
        fill: options.fill
    });

    var label = new fabric.Text(options.label);

    var group = new fabric.Group([rect, label]);

    group.left = options.left;
    group.top = options.top;

    group.toSVG = function() {
        var e=[];
        for(var t = 0; t < this._objects.length; t++)
            e.push(this._objects[t].toSVG());

        return'<g transform="'+this.getSvgTransform()+'">'+e.join("")+"</g>"
    };

    return group;
};
```

The reason I overwrote `toSVG` is because the default implementation cycles through the children in reverse order (`for(var t=this._objects.length;t--;)`). I have no clue why it does that, but the text renders underneath the rectangle.