# Fabric js canvas.toSVG() method throwing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

When i tried to export my canvas data to svg using the canvas.toSVG() method, it throws an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<klass> has no method 'toSVG'`
Is this an issue with the library or am i doing anything wrong?
[image: error shown on the console of chrome]

Can anybody tell me why this happens ? advance thanks for any help.

**Update :** issue solved
Actually i was using the version 1.2.0, that time this issue came then i changed the version to 1.3.7, that solved the issue

Comment: This can maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848362/tosvg-method-not-working-on-extended-class-with-fabric-js

Comment: Can you give us more information. Which fabric version? Do you use subclasses?
JSON representation of your canvas would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. actually i was using the version 1.2.0, that time this issue came then i changed the version to 1.3.7, that solved the issue